# Piwik analytics, custom variables and reporting

Tags: piwik

I am logging some custom variables via the javascript tracker (which unimportant for this question most likely).

I can see the variables and their values in the Custom Variables section of my Piwik site so I know they are recording.

When I create a report however it generates something with just the names of my variables. I don't see any aggregation or mention of the actual values for the custom variables. Is something that I can get out of the box or am I going to have to dig into the reporting api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found out:

1) Load the Custom Variables dashboard widget.

2) If you hover over the dashboard widget you will see an icon that looks like 2 squares overlapping each other. The hover label reads 'Maximise'. Click it.

3) The widget should now be in a modal window. In the lower right there is a gear icon. Click it and select 'Make it flat'. This causes the report to include the data when you export it.

4) In the lower left of the modal dialog there are a series of icons. The last icon looks like a box with an arrow in it pointing right. The hover label reads 'Export this data in other formats'. Click this and export. The variable names AND values should be there.

You can also avoid popping it out by clicking the little (not) obvious arrow.

And my post from Piwik forums: http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?15,117322